# Godot 4.1 Spatial Shaders : Possible to change projection direction of texture?

Tags: projection, fragment-shader, godot4, godot-shader-language

I am trying to apply a 2D texture to a 3D sphere. To do this, I create a Surface Material Override with a StandardMaterial3D, then plug the texture into the albedo.
The problem is that the projection only seems to come from the [negative z direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZv89.jpg), while I would like it to come from the top (positive y direction).

I am new to spatial shaders and do not know if there is a simple way to do this, since modifying parameters in the UV section will only lead to modifying the texture itself, and not the way it is projected.
I know this is technically feasible by simply rotating the mesh, but since I will later move on to non symmetric meshes, I prefer only controlling the shader for now.